# Two non-identity elements in PSL(2,C) commute iff

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation, linear-groups

I know non-identity 2 elements in $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ commutes iff they have the same fixed points in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$.

But for $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})=Isom^{+}(\mathbb{H}^3)$, it seems a bit tricky for the iff conclusion.(Sharing fixed points in $\hat{\mathbb{R}^3}$+ some condition)

For $A$ being parabolic or hyperbolic, it seems same conclusion that $B$ also is parabolic or hyperbolic preserving same fixed points.

For $A$ being elliptic, $B$ also must preserve the same fixe point with $A$ and there is some extra condition I think. It seems related to under what condition two elements in $SO(3)$ commutes?

Any Guru can shine some light on this? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266465/when-do-two-elements-of-so3-commute
I found an useful link for myself.

Comment: I kind of get it after the reading that question. btw, my question can be a fun for you!

Comment: This statement is false in $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ and it is false in $PSL(2,\mathbb C)$. For example, the identity element of $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ commutes with every other element of $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$, but it is the only element that fixes every point of $\hat{\mathbb C}$.

Comment: Ah to clarify, I meant 2 non-identity elements to commute.